# Convert link in Wordpress 3.2.1

Tags: cms, urls, links

How can I convert links (url displayed in the browser) from :

```
www.mywebsite.com/?p=13
```

to something like this :

```
www.mywebsite.com/title_of_the_topic
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to Settings->Permalinks, select Custom Structure, and set the text box to just `/%postname%/`

<strike>You might consider the second bullet point [in the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags) recommending against this particular URL pattern, though.</strike> [This was addressed in 3.3](http://ottopress.com/2011/how-the-postname-permalinks-in-wordpress-3-3-work/?utm_source=WPmail.me+List&utm_campaign=259daa9abe-ga&utm_medium=email)